# vPopmail / xinetd

Tags: email-server, email

I'm attempting to setup vpopmail on my CentOS server (Media Temple). Everything is working like a charm, with the exception that I cannot login to the server from any pop3 client. Upon trying to login I get the following error:

```
 Sending of password did not succeed. Mail server mail.(mydomain).com responded: Login failed.
```

I'm running qmail (of course) with xinetd (not tcpserver). I've placed a file called `pop3` into the folder `/etc/xinetd.d` with the content:

```
service pop3
{
    disable              = no
    socket_type          = stream
    protocol             = tcp
    wait                 = no
    user                 = root
    server               = /var/qmail/bin/qmail-popup
    server_args          = mail.(mydomain).com /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw /var/qmail/bin/qmail-pop3d Maildir
    log_type             = FILE /var/log/xinetd.log
    log_on_success       = HOST
    log_on_failure       = HOST RECORD
}
```

Can anybody offer any guidance here? I've been unsuccessfully trying to make this happen for over a week.

Answer (score 1):

In your pop settings of the mail client are you specifying your full email address for your username?  Also set your firewall to log all connections from your IP and confirm you are connecting on the correct ports.

Comment: I am. As for the firewall, I can confirm that I'm able to connect to the qmail server and successfully authenticate on a qmail user if not attempting to do so through vPopmail.

Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: Also, to actually answer your question: No, I'm not working behind a firewall at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Some offtopic, but probably it's worth to follow some qmail guides. There are nice recommendations from John Simpson *("Setting up an SMTP service")* and so on. It's working for me, but I'm using tcpserver.